# Why the need to use the Accusative case instead of the Dative in "ab nächsten Monat"?

Tags: grammatical-case

> Ab **nächsten** Monat bekomme ich ...

The prepostion *ab* should be followed by the Dative case, and the Starke Flexion applies here, so I'm tempted to say "ab nächste**m** Monat" instead of "ab nächste**n** Monat".

Comment: *nä**chstem** **M**onat* is hard to pronouce. People usually get both *ab nächstem Jahr* and *seit vorigem Monat* right, but everyone stumbles about the *nächstem Monat* and accidentally hits the **n**. Don't worry too much about it.

Comment: @Janka The pronunciation is not a good explanation. The same thing works with *Samstag*, which doesn't hit a double "m".

Comment: For me, its the whole chst consonant cluster followed by a non-silient em and another m. I always hear people helping themselves out by mumbling *ab nächstm'Monat*, dropping the e, even pulling together the two m's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two factors coincide:

1. The German dative is slowly dying, being replaced by other cases across the board. We may not see the last of it, but our descendants surely will.
2. No matter how you *intend* to pronounce it, in practice,  "einen"+"Monat" is indistinguishable from "einem"+"Monat" anyway because of coarticulation. Therefore, people who spell "by ear" have even less incentive than usual to preserve the dative in this construction.

Comment: I'd thought it was the genitive that was an endangered species?

Comment: @tofro The entire case system is on its way out. The genitive is the first to go because it's already the least-used case, but the dative is going the same way. Most dative noun endings are already gone; only the more frequent pronouns and articles are still resisting.

Comment: But it's not like this is going to happen next month. We might have to wait 500 more years until we'll finally lose the dative...

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you may use **both** dative and accusative with *ab* in a temporary usage.

> ab nächstem Monat
>
> ab nächsten Monat

Duden uses the example

> ab kommendem/(auch:) kommenden Montag

Note the accusative usage is restricted to the above shortened form. As soon as you introduce an article, like in

> ab dem nächsten Montag
>
> <s>ab den nächsten Montag</s>

accusative no longer works.